# Subgroup of rotations in $D_n$ is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is what I did:

Suppose R $\leq$ $D_n$ is the subgroup of rotation. Suppose $x \in fRf^{-1}$. Then $x = frf^{-1}$ for some r and for any r. Therefore, $x = r'$ a rotation and hence $x \in R$. therefore by definition R is normal in $D_n$

Is this correct and complete verification?

Thanks, any other suggestions??

Comment: Any subgroup of index 2 of any group is normal.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, this is faster.

Comment: but the argument above is correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand your statement "Then $x = frf^{-1}$ for some $r$ and for any $r$". There are certainly more elegant ways of doing it, but my personal approach would be to show that $x$ is a rotation by using the fact that every $f \in D_n$ is generated by the elements $r,s$ satisfying $s^2 = 1$ and $srs = r^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is correct. But you should emphasize and expand a bit more the essence of the thought, and this is:

> Therefore $x=frf^{-1}$ is a *rotation*.

So.. Why is it a rotation? That's the point.